# Move to trash when deleted using OpenPop.NET

Tags: c#, .net, pop3

I'm trying to delete messages from mailbox using pop3Client, but the messages are permanently getting deleted from mailbox, Do we have any option to show messages in trash when deleted.

My code:

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
 {
        // Connect to the server
        client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

        // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
        client.Authenticate(username, password);

        // Get the number of messages in the inbox
        int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

        //My logic

        client.DeleteAllMessages();

    }
```

Comment: POP3 doesn't have the concept of a trash, or any folder-based organization for that matter. You want IMAP.

Comment: @madreflection - Due i need to change DL(mailbox) to IMAP ?

Comment: Not enough information to answer that.

Comment: when we delete from mailbox its shows in the trash, but when we delete through code its permanently deleted, why that so ?

Comment: The "trash" concept is happening locally, not on the server. POP3 is based on retrieving messages to local storage. A POP3 client downloads messages and then removes them from the server. Message management happens locally. By *"when we delete"*, you're talking about local message management, not actions on the server.

Comment: That is, unless you're unintentionally mixing the two. I guess I have to ask this question now: why did you decide to use POP3 here?

Comment: Mail account was configured as pop3

Comment: In that case, there are no folders on the server. Thus, the only trash you have is where you put the message after you download it. The only folders you'll have is what your application provides. Good luck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misunderstanding of the technology involved.